# How do I pass a docstring to pybind11::def_property_readonly?

Tags: pybind11

I am trying to add a documented readonly property to a class in a python extension defined using pybind11. Usually this is done by adding a string argument to the define call. However, when I add a string argument to the readonly property definition call, I get template compile errors.

Compiles but doesn't have a docstring:

```
[...]
.def_property_readonly(
        "property_name",
        [](){ return ""; })
[...]
```

Has a docstring but doesn't compile:

```
[...]
.def_property_readonly(
        "property_name",
        [](){ return ""; },
        std::string("docstring"))
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a `const char *` instead of a `std::string`.

```
[...]
.def_property_readonly(
        "property_name",
        [](){ return ""; },
        "const char docstring")
[...]
```